Horizontal scroll with anchor links - divs not scaling properly
I'm trying to use anchor links to trigger different horizontal scroll divs to appear.
I have a master container that holds multiple children: the children are all fixed width and height to fill the master container, with overflow-x enabled. Each child is stacked vertically on top of one another, so each jump link to a child reveals only that child:
https://i.imgur.com/ZUiUDKd.png
The children scale with their parent container, but the anchor point won't stay positioned to the top left of the parent container, thus revealing all of the hidden children when the window is scaled:
https://i.imgur.com/5emHc4O.gif
(https://jsfiddle.net/wpt9of8j/2/)

Fiddle is here. Any ideas on how I could go about fixing this (or getting a similar result using JS)?

You want to use scroll snapping.
.scroll {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    scroll-snap-type: block mandatory;
}

.section {
    /* all you existing styles */
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}


As a general comment unrelated to your question, I’d highly recommend learning CSS Grid layout. It would make your overall app structure much more straightforward (once you get over the learning curve).
